# PerformancePoint Services 2010 - Reuse dashboards in external standalone ASP.Net application?

Tags: 2010, web-part, asp.net, performancepoint

I am a newbie to PerformancePoint Services 2010 & Sharepoint 2010. Assuming we have the necessary licenses, we are wondering what is the best option to include the dashboards developed in PPS/SP 2010 in a pre-existing ASP.Net application. Looks like PPS 2010 is closely tied up with SP 2010. Is there anyway to reuse the dashboards, apart from using the URL of the Dashboard directly (meaning without having to deploy SP & PPS in Production), for example using some webparts in the ASP.Net app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a response from another source: PerformancePoint 2010 is closely tied up with Sharepoint. Hence cannot be used standalone. Only work around: reuse via an IFrame and point to the URL of PerformancePoint dashboards.

Answer (score 0):

> Got a response from another source: PerformancePoint 2010 is closely tied up with Sharepoint. Hence cannot be used standalone. Only work around: reuse via an IFrame and point to the URL of PerformancePoint dashboards.

1. By including in the IFrame, you had the entire SharePoint site (themes, etc) in your standalone ASP.NET site; in other wordes it was not seamless?
2. Did you lose drilldown functionality in your dashboard?  I've read there are issues when using the IFrame solution.

Comment: We dropped that idea as our team was not comfortable using iFrames.

Comment: Not comfortable using iframes? Look out for the 2013 app model...

Comment: We decided to use an iframe and made it look as seamless as possible in our application.  Our drilldown functionality was also left intact and didn't have any issues.  Why is your team not comfortable with iframes?  What did you guys implement in place of iframes?